# Calculating time and space asymptotic complexity of a function

Tags: c, function, time-complexity, space-complexity

I've just started learning time and space complexity and I'm having trouble in calculating it for this program.

```
void f(int n){
    int a[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        a[k % 4] *=3;
    }
    int** ptr = (int **)malloc(a[0]*sizeof(int*));
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0]; j++) {
        *(ptr+j) = (int*)malloc(j*sizeof(int));
        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
            printf("*");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the methods that I learned but im not sure how to use them correctly.

Can somebody explain me how to find the complexity of this example?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Don't use `*(ptr + i)`, use `ptr[i]`.

Comment: What's the reason for `ptr`? You allocate it, but never use it for anything.

Comment: This function is just for training

Comment: You basically have to figure out how `a[0]` grows as a function of `n`, since that bounds the second loop. `malloc()` itself is O(1).

Comment: @Barmar: Re “`malloc()` itself is O(1)”: Source? There is no loop at all in a typical `malloc` implementation, except one with constant loop bounds? No searching a list or tree or other data structure for a block of suitable size? Even disregarding the fact the operating system has to clear memory when providing new memory to a process?

Comment: None of that is a function of N. So it's asymptotically constant time as far as the caller is concerned.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Clearing the memory would be O(n). But most calls to `malloc()` don't require getting memory from the OS, it's just reusing memory already in the heap. So it's in the noise.

Comment: @Barmar: How does `malloc` find a block of sufficient size in its pool without using some form of loop?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It uses some kind of loop, but the loop iterations are not a function of `N`. It's a black box, you can't account for it in the time complexity of the caller.

Comment: @Barmar: You do not know whether it is a function of `n`; calling it repeatedly will affect its data structures, and it will have some varying behavior over the sequences of calls. If it is a black box, you cannot say it is O(1).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since it's a black box you can't say anything about its effect on the complexity. So you just ignore it. Just like you ignore the complexity of array indexing, arithmetic operations, etc.

Comment: @Barmar: Re “Since it's a black box you can't say anything about its effect on the complexity. So you just ignore it.”: That is not a correct approach. Re “Just like you ignore the complexity of array indexing, arithmetic operations, etc.”: These are not ignored; the complexity is expressed in a model of [arithmetic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Others) rather than the model of bit complexity. Bit complexity is the model used in computer science theory…

Comment: … Arithmetic complexity is a practical model for characterizing performance of real-world programs that will not overflow their bounds, and it is understood that, if they needed to exceed their word size, the run-time would be different. If OP wants the bit complexity, then the complexity of array indexing and arithmetic operations cannot be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop iterates `n` times. The body is a constant-time equation, so the loop is O(n).

Each time the loop cycles through the `a` array, it multiplies the elements by 3, so the result is that the value of each element is asymptotically proportional to 3<sup>n</sup>.

The only element that matters for the second loop is `a[0]`. So the outer loop iterates O(3<sup>n</sup>) times.

The inner loop iterates `j` times, where `j` goes from 0 to 3<sup>n</sup>-1. The formula for the sum of the sequence 1, 2, ... x is `x * (x + 1) / 2`, which is O(x<sup>2</sup>).

When you combine these, the resulting complexity is O((3<sup>n</sup>)<sup>2</sup>).

The space complexity is the same, since the total size of the arrays allocated in the loop are the same as the number of iterations of the inner loop.

Comment: Re “The time complexity of nested loops is the complexity of the outer loop times the complexity of the inner loop”: That may hold for simple loops, but it is not true in general, so it should not be stated as a principle without some contingency. If there are some interactions between the inner and outer loops, the total complexity may be different.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Can you explain more about the way you combined them int the 5th paragraph?